# How can I restore an item to my Windows 7 start menu?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I was recently "upgraded" from Win XP to Windows 7 and had to install lots of additional software.  One of the products did not create a desktop shortcut.  I inadvertently "moved" the shortcut from the "Start -> All Programs" list to my desktop instead of copying (by dragging the link from the list displayed).

How do I restore this program such that it is listed in the "Start" menu again?

I have created a new link here:

`C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\SAS`

But the "Start" menu still does not display the program.

I also found this location, but it does not have all the other programs:

`C:\Users\BD9439\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\SAS`

I also see the link defined here, as are all the other products:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\SAS`

Note that `SAS` is a family of products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Click Start, find the program, right-click it, and then click Pin to Start Menu.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this page, I think this would work for you aswell... It should!
http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.se/2009/05/story-of-windows-7-and-empty-all.html

Otherwise, try doing a system restore.
Good luck!